# Karaf unable to install jena

Tags: jena, apache-karaf

I'm trying to install jena (as a requirement of [Islandora](https://islandora.github.io/documentation/installation/manual/installing_karaf_and_alpaca/#installing-the-required-karaf-features)), running Karaf 4.2.11, however when I run the command to install, `/opt/karaf/bin/client feature:install jena`, an error is returned. I got the full text of the error, located below, from the Karaf log.

```
2021-09-14T11:10:00,610 | ERROR | Thread-57        | ShellUtil                        | 38 - org.apache.karaf.shell.core - 4.2.11 | Exception caught while executing command
org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=jena; type=karaf.feature; version="[4.1.0,4.1.0]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=jena)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=4.1.0)(version<=4.1.0))" [caused by: Unable to resolve jena/4.1.0: missing requirement [jena/4.1.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.apache.jena.osgi; type=osgi.bundle; version="[4.1.0,4.1.0]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.jena.osgi/4.1.0: missing requirement [org.apache.jena.osgi/4.1.0] osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"]]
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1343) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.doResolve(ResolverImpl.java:392) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:378) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:332) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:257) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:401) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1063) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:998) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292]
Caused by: org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve jena/4.1.0: missing requirement [jena/4.1.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.apache.jena.osgi; type=osgi.bundle; version="[4.1.0,4.1.0]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.jena.osgi/4.1.0: missing requirement [org.apache.jena.osgi/4.1.0] osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"]
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1343) ~[?:?]
        ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve org.apache.jena.osgi/4.1.0: missing requirement [org.apache.jena.osgi/4.1.0] osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1343) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1343) ~[?:?]
        ... 12 more
```

I've not used Karaf before, but I've looked through a lot of issues and can't seem to decipher the error, though I think it has to do with the Java version? I'm running version 11.0.11 of openJDK. It seems to me like that's the version it's asking for, though. Is there some configuration I'm missing?

I'm happy to supply any other troubleshooting info, I just can't find where to go from here, not having worked with Karaf before.

Comment: Islandora has a slack channel and mailing lists https://islandora.ca/index.php/community which also provide places to ask the question (please post any answers you get back here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that Karaf is being run with Java 8. You can see evidence of that in the line:

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292]
```

(The execution environment is Java 1.8.0_292)

Jena 4.x requires Java 11+

In order to use Java 11, be sure to set the JAVA_HOME environment value to point to the correct installation. On linux-based environments, this can often be handled with the `update-alternatives --config java` command

Comment: This was the solution thank you so much. I had to make sure that the JAVA_HOME was set in the setenv file for karaf as well and then make sure to stop and restart the karaf service.